# Error : Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataadapter

I am using Paging to show data in `datagridview`, but when i try to Update any data with `updatebutton` data should be updated In `datagridview` as well as in database.

But I get this error:

> Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection
>   with modified rows

which happens on this line:

```
adp1.Update(dt);//here I am getting error
```

Below is the code

```
public partial class EditMediClgList : Form
    {        
        public EditMediClgList()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=db1.mdb");
                con.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error:" +err);
            }

            cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Select * from MedicalColeges order by MedicalClgID", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
            adp1.Fill(ds, "MedicalColeges");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;

            // Get total count of the pages; 
            this.CalculateTotalPages();
            // Load the first page of data; 
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = GetCurrentRecords(1, con);

        }
        private void CalculateTotalPages()
        {
            int rowCount = ds.Tables["MedicalColeges"].Rows.Count;
            this.TotalPage = rowCount / PageSize;
            if (rowCount % PageSize > 0) // if remainder is more than  zero 
            {
                this.TotalPage += 1;
            }
        }
        private DataTable GetCurrentRecords(int page, OleDbConnection con)
        {
             dt = new DataTable();

            if (page == 1)
            {
                cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize + " * from MedicalColeges ORDER BY MedicalClgID", con);
                // CurrentPageIndex++;
            }
            else
            {
                int PreviouspageLimit = (page - 1) * PageSize;

                cmd2 = new OleDbCommand("Select TOP " + PageSize +
                    " * from MedicalColeges " +
                    "WHERE MedicalClgID NOT IN " +
                "(Select TOP " + PreviouspageLimit + " MedicalClgID from MedicalColeges ORDER BY MedicalClgID) ", con); // +
                //"order by customerid", con);
            }
            try
            {
                // con.Open();
                this.adp1.SelectCommand = cmd2;
                this.adp1.Fill(dt);
                txtPaging.Text = string.Format("page{0} of {1} pages", this.CurrentPageIndex, this.TotalPage);
            }
            finally
            {
               // con.Close();
            }
            return dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                adp1.Update(dt);//here I am getting error
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have Created the `OleDbDataAdapter` with a `Select` command only:

```
adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1);
```

**`OleDbDataAdapter`** requires valid `Update`, `Insert,` `Delete` commands to be used to save the data like this:

```
adp1.Update(dt);//here I am getting error
```

You just need to use a `OleDbCommandBuilder` that will generate the commands for you:

```
adp1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adp1.SelectCommand = cmd1; // cmd1 is your SELECT command
OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp1);
```

**EDIT**

Since you change the Select command of the `OleDbDataAdapter` at runtime for paging, what your need is to initialize each time you save data:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {                
            adp1.SelectCommand = cmd1; // cmd1 is your SELECT command
            OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adp1);
            adp1.Update(dt); //here I hope you won't get error :-)
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes you are right ,now I am not getting error and data is updated,Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

It could be that you are missing Primary Key in the table. You need to make sure primary key is set on a column in your data base table.

Answer (score 1):

I had to alter my (incrementing) index column to the [primary key of my table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8859374/1466951) (as Eaint suggest). After this, I had to pull up the DataSet.xsd in designer view, right click on the visual DataTable object and select configure. When the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard opened, I clicked the Advanced Options button. I checked the Generate Insert, Update and Delete statements checkbox then OK and Finish. After this (still in designer view), I selected the visual TableAdapter object which gave me all the full properties.  The SQL was autogenerated.  Took a while for me to track this down, so I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to "@Chris" the code above works for me.
I needed to specify the Database Table name that will be updated when I Update.
You can read more about that here:

[DataAdapter: Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228608/dataadapter-update-unable-to-find-tablemappingtable-or-datatable-table)

```
// This Adapter and Dataset are used for Populating my datagridview, 
// so I use them also when I need to Update the Datagridview

SqlDataAdapter kundeTlfAdapter;
DataSet kundeTlfDataSet; 

try
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data source=BG-1-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Advokathuset; User Id = abc; Password = abc;");
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select* From Kunde_Tlf", connection);
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(kundeTlfAdapter);
    kundeTlfAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd1; // cmd1 is your SELECT command

    kundeTlfAdapter.Update(kundeTlfDataSet, "Kunde_Tlf"); //I get eror here if I dont add the name of the table that needs Update "Kunde_Tlf"
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
}
```