# DataAdapter: Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dataadapter

This code snippet is throwing an error:

> Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.) on adapter.Update(ds); line

Why it is throwing this type of error?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = connectionString();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Cars";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);

SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

adapter.Fill(ds, "Cars");

//Code to modify data in the DataSet
ds.Tables["Cars"].Rows[0]["Brand"] = "NewBrand";

adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
adapter.Update(ds);
```

Answer (score 12):

Use

```
adapter.Update(ds, "Cars");
```

instead.

I have tested it. I got the same error without and it works if i specify the tablename. However, i must admit that i yet don't know why the `DataAdapter` needs to know the table-name since it has all informations it needs. If i use[`ds.GetChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ey25we.aspx) i get one row with the correct table-name.

**Update** I have found nothing on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at8a576f.aspx) but finally found it in the source(ILSpy). Here is the implementation of `DBDataAdapter.Update(DataSet)`:

```
public override int Update(DataSet dataSet)
{
    return this.Update(dataSet, "Table");
}
```

So if you don't specify a table, the table-name `"Table"` is used and if you've specified a table-name other than that you'll get this error, that's really strange!

I assume that the reason for this is that the `DataAdapter` cannot call `GetChanges` to determine the table to update for two reasons:

1. It would be inefficient since it needs to loop all tables and all of their rows to find rows with a `RowState` != `Unchanged`
2. It's possible that multiple tables needs to be updated since they contain changed rows. That is not supported via `DataAdapter`. Hence `DataAdapter.Update(DataSet)` assumes the default name `"Table"` as table-name.

**Edit**: However, maybe someone can explain me why the `DataAdapter` doesn't use `DataSet.Tables[0].TableName` instead.

So in general it seems to be best practise to specify the name of the table you want to update.

Comment: Thank you Tim Schmelter.

Answer (score 2):

It's because .NET cannot assume that the table name in the `DataSet`/`DataTable` is identical to the database table. Thus .NET warns you about it.

To solve it you need to add a mapping to the `DataAdapter`:

```
da.TableMappings.Add("TableNameInDb", "TableNameInTheDataSet");
```

However, even if you have specified a name in the `DataSet` or the `DataSource` it still doesn't work, since the adapter seems to forget the name.

I only got it working by using:

```
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TableNameInDb");
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with jgauffin and I will only explain it with more text.

First, I must explain how `TableMapping` works. If we don't specify `TableMappings` with `SqlDataAdapter` (`SqlDataAdapter` that will fill our `DataSet`) then by default the first table will be named "Table", the second will be named "Table1", the third will be named "Table2" etc.

So, when we want to name `DataTable` in `DataSet`, we use it like this:

```
System.Data.DataSet myDataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(dbCommand))
{
    dbAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Cars");
    dbAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Trucks");
        //...

    dbAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);
}
```

And only then we can modify it like this:

```
myDataSet.Tables["Cars"].Rows[0]["Brand"] = "Toyota";
myDataSet.Tables["Trucks"].Rows[0]["Brand"] = "MAN";
```