# update command C# DataGridView to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I'm attempting to update a SQL table from C# project datagridview "Work_Table". However when I attempt to make the update I get this error

"Update unable to find TableMapping ['Work_Table'] or DataTable 'Work_Table'"

Any ideas?

Here is my code below:

```
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                string query = @"Select * from person.addresstype";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                dAdapter.Update(ds, "Work_Table");

                MessageBox.Show("Saved");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataAdapter: Update unable to find TableMapping\['Table'\] or DataTable 'Table'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228608/dataadapter-update-unable-to-find-tablemappingtable-or-datatable-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `DataTable` from the `.DataSource` property of the grid.  This will have the information on what was added, updated and deleted.

You can skip the command and pass the select string and connection string directly to the `DataAdapter` constructor.

Create a `CommandBuilder` to provide the Insert, Update and Delete text for the `DataAdapter.Update`. Pass the `DataAdapter` to the constructor of the `CommandBuilder`.

```
    private string connString = "Your connection string";
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
        try
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter dAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from person.addresstype", connString))
            using (SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(dAdapter))
            {
                dAdapter.Update(dt);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        } 
    }
```