# Does DbDataAdapter.Fill guarantee returned table names to be Table, Table1, Table2 etc.?

Tags: c#, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

From [MS doc for DBDataAdapter.Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.fill?view=net-7.0#system-data-common-dbdataadapter-fill(system-data-dataset)):

> When the query specified returns multiple results, the result set for
> each row returning query is placed in a separate table. Additional
> result sets are named by appending integral values to the specified
> table name (for example, "Table", "Table1", "Table2", and so on).

And I can see from the example for [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0) that they use *Table*:

```
//Create a SqlDataAdapter for the Suppliers table.
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

// A table mapping names the DataTable.
adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Suppliers");

// Open the connection.
connection.Open();
Console.WriteLine("The SqlConnection is open.");

// Create a SqlCommand to retrieve Suppliers data.
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT SupplierID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Suppliers;",
    connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// Set the SqlDataAdapter's SelectCommand.
adapter.SelectCommand = command;

// Fill the DataSet.
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("Suppliers");
adapter. Fill(dataset);
```

But are Table, Table1, Table2 and so on guaranteed? Can I safely use them when I want to set custom names for the DataSet tables with TableMappings?

Comment: If you only have a single table use [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-7.0) instead. [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-7.0) is if you need to have multiple DataTables and need to create relationships between them.

Comment: @user09938 I intend to retrieve 5 tables with a single query and put them into a DataSet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following two tables (in SQL Server):

**Employee**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(Id int not null Identity(1,1),
                      FirstName varchar(50),
                      LastName varchar(50),
                      CONSTRAINT PK_Employee_Id Primary Key(Id));
```

**Asset**:

```
CREATE TABLE Asset(Id int Identity(1,1),
                   Manufacturer varchar(50),
                   Model varchar(50),
                   Description varchar(50),
                   Category varchar(25),
                   Comments varchar(150),
                   EmployeeId int,
                   CONSTRAINT PK_Asset_Id Primary Key(Id),
                   Constraint FK_Asset_EmployeeId_Employee_Id Foreign Key(EmployeeId) references Employee(Id))"
```

Try the following:

**Add the following using directives**:

- `using System.Configuration;`
- `using System.Data;`
- `using System.Data.SqlClient;`
- `using System.Diagnostics;`

**App.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionStringWindowsAuth" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HR;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionStringWindowsAuthMars" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=HR;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionStringSqlServerAuth" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=HR;User Id=testUser;Password=mySuperSecretPassword;" />
        <add name="ConnectionStringSqlServerAuthMars" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=HR;User Id=testUser;Password=mySuperSecretPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

**GetData**:

```
private string _connectionStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSqlServerAuth"].ConnectionString;
private string _connectionStrMars = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringSqlServerAuthMars"].ConnectionString;

public DataSet GetData()
{
    //create new instance
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee", con);
            DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable("Employee");
            da.Fill(dtEmployee);

            //add
            ds.Tables.Add(dtEmployee);

            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Asset", con);
            DataTable dtAsset = new DataTable("Asset");
            da.Fill(dtAsset);

            //add
            ds.Tables.Add(dtAsset);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"dt[{dt.TableName}] row count: {dt.Rows.Count}");

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"    ColumnName: {col.ColumnName}");
                }

                Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

> But are Table, Table1, Table2 and so on guaranteed?

According to [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter#multiple-result-sets), it states:

> **Multiple Result Sets**
>
> If the DataAdapter encounters multiple result sets, it creates
> multiple tables in the DataSet. The tables are given an incremental
> default name of TableN, starting with "Table" for Table0. If a table
> name is passed as an argument to the Fill method, the tables are given
> an incremental default name of TableNameN, starting with "TableName"
> for TableName0.

Let's add some sample data:

**Employee**:

[image]

**Asset**:

[image]

If we execute the following code:

```
//Note: This doesn't work correctly

public DataSet GetData()
{
    //create new instance
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        //open
        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            //1st query
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee", con);
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"dt[{dt.TableName}] row count: {dt.Rows.Count}{Environment.NewLine}");

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"    ColumnName: {col.ColumnName}");
                }
            }

            //2nd query
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Asset", con);
            da.Fill(ds);

            Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"dt[{dt.TableName}] row count: {dt.Rows.Count}{Environment.NewLine}");

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"    ColumnName: {col.ColumnName}");
                }
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
dt[Table] row count: 3

    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: FirstName
    ColumnName: LastName

dt[Table] row count: 7

    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: FirstName
    ColumnName: LastName
    ColumnName: Manufacturer
    ColumnName: Model
    ColumnName: Description
    ColumnName: Category
    ColumnName: Comments
    ColumnName: EmployeeId
```

As you can see, the table name is `Table`, in both the 1st and 2nd query. Additionally, the column names from the 2nd query were added to the table (name: "Table") in the DataSet. The final result is a table with 3 + 4 = 7 rows. This isn't the desired result.

Let's try with multiple result sets (ie: more than one select statement within a single SelectCommand). We'll use 2 select queries separated by semi-colon: `SELECT * FROM Employee; SELECT * FROM Asset;`

```
public DataSet GetDataMultipleResultSets()
{
    //create new instance
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //'Open' is explicitly called; the connection will be opened implicitly
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee; SELECT * FROM Asset;", con);
            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"dt[{dt.TableName}] row count: {dt.Rows.Count}");

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"    ColumnName: {col.ColumnName}");
                }

                Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
dt[Table] row count: 3
    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: FirstName
    ColumnName: LastName

dt[Table1] row count: 4
    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: Manufacturer
    ColumnName: Model
    ColumnName: Description
    ColumnName: Category
    ColumnName: Comments
    ColumnName: EmployeeId
```

This is one gives the desired result, however as stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter#multiple-result-sets) the table names are `Table` and `Table1`.

If one desires for each `DataTable` within a `DataSet` to have the same name as the table within the database, one can use [DataAdapter.TableMappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-common-dataadapter-tablemappings) as shown below:

```
public DataSet GetDataMultipleResultSets()
{
    //create new instance
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    //'Open' is explicitly called; the connection will be opened implicitly
    //using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStrMars))
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            //DataSet tables names are 'Table' (ie: Table0), 'Table1', 'Table2', 'Table3', etc...
            //which is determined by the number of queries one specifies within a SelectCommand

            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee; SELECT * FROM Asset;", con);

            //since we have 2 select statements, 
            //the table names in the DataSet will be 'Table' and 'Table1'
            //if we had 3 select statements, 
            //the table names in the DataSet would be 'Table', 'Table1', and 'Table2'
            da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Employee");
            da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Asset");

            da.Fill(ds);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"dt[{dt.TableName}] row count: {dt.Rows.Count}");

                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"    ColumnName: {col.ColumnName}");
                }

                Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
dt[Employee] row count: 3
    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: FirstName
    ColumnName: LastName

dt[Asset] row count: 4
    ColumnName: Id
    ColumnName: Manufacturer
    ColumnName: Model
    ColumnName: Description
    ColumnName: Category
    ColumnName: Comments
    ColumnName: EmployeeId
```

Notice that for each `DataTable` within the `DataSet`, that the name now matches the name of table in the database (`Employee` and `Asset`).

---

**Summary**:

**Given**:

- `SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr)`
- `SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter()`

As demonstrated above, for a single result set (ie: a single select statement within a [SelectCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)),

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee;", con);
da.Fill(ds);
```

**or**

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Asset;", con);
da.Fill(ds);
```

the result is the (default) DataTable name `Table`.

If one uses multiple result sets (ie: multiple select statements within a [SelectCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)),

```
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employee; SELECT * FROM Asset;", con);
da.Fill(ds);
```

the result is the (default) DataTable names `Table`, `Table1`, etc.., unless one adds a mapping using [DataAdapter.TableMappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.tablemappings?view=net-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#system-data-common-dataadapter-tablemappings).

---

**Resources**:

- [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)
- [SqlDataAdapter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0)
- [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19228608/dataadapter-update-unable-to-find-tablemappingtable-or-datatable-table)
- [ADO.NET Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview)
- [Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-and-modifying-data)
- [ADO.NET DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-datasets)
- [DataSets, DataTables, and DataViews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/)
- [Creating a DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/creating-a-dataset)
- [Adding a DataTable to a DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/adding-a-datatable-to-a-dataset)
- [DataAdapters and DataReaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapters-and-datareaders)
- [Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter#multiple-result-sets)
- [SqlDataAdapter and multiple result sets](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b1ca8b13-9fb7-463d-9f62-b250430570fa/sqldataadapter-and-multiple-result-sets?forum=aspwebformsdata)

**Additional Resources**:

- [Create relationships between datasets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/relationships-in-datasets?view=vs-2022)
- [DataRelation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarelation?view=net-7.0)
- [DataTableCollection.Add Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatablecollection.add?view=net-7.0)
- [C# Multiple Result Sets](http://csharp.net-informations.com/data-providers/csharp-multiple-resultsets.htm)

Comment: Thanks for showing me how I can replace SelectCommand and FIll to name result tables directly, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @formicini: The updated post and/or resources should answer your question.