# Table primary unique index as two columns?

Tags: mysql, indexing

How can I define a primary key in my table as two unique fields?

I have several columns in my table and I have two keys: `ID` and `SOURCE`.  Values for `ID` can appear twice in the column, but the combination of ID + SOURCE can be relied on as a primary key.

For example:

```
              ID | SOURCE | TEXT
              ------------------
UNIQUE -      2312 | FB | BLA BLA  
UNIQUE -      2312 | MU | BLA BLA
```

I'm using MySQL database.  How I can I make the primary key on two columns?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ALTER TABLE to add a composite primary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859353/alter-table-to-add-a-composite-primary-key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constraint to enforce uniqueness enforced on two columns:

```
Alter table table_name add CONSTRAINT constr_ID unique (ID,SOURCE);
```

OR add a constraint primary key enforced on two columns:

```
 Alter table table_name add  PRIMARY KEY (id, source);
```

Comment: What CONSTRAINT is doing?

Answer (score 3):

You may use the `ALTER TABLE` syntax, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD CONSTRAINT my_table_pk PRIMARY KEY (id, source);
```

Also, this can be defined in `CREATE TABLE`, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id int,
  source varchar(3),
  text varchar(20),
  PRIMARY_KEY(id, source)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'm picking Aman's question because he have less points though your answer was more detailed.

Comment: @Yehonatan I appreciate your effort around community building. Your comment reminds me of similar scenario a couple of years ago when my reputation points were low, a user gave same reason for accepting my answer over a high-rep user :)

Comment: @Thanks :) I'm trying to help as much as I can