# Insert 2 values into mysql table only if both values are unique together

Tags: mysql

I want data to be inserted into mysql table only if both fields are unique.  For example:

```
ID   VALUE
__   _____
1    abc  //INSERT
2    abc  //INSERT
3    def  //INSERT
1    def  //INSERT
2    abc  //INSERT SHOULD NOT BE PROCESSED
```

WHats the most efficient way to do accomplish this and also only using mysql.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_t_id_value on t(id, value);
```

This will prevent duplicated values from being inserted into the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a composite key (multi-column).

```
Create table myTable(
...
PRIMARY KEY (ID, VALUE)
)
```

When you try insert to

```
2    abc
```

you will have **duplicate entry error message** and if you can not create the table [you can ALTER TABLE like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859353/alter-table-to-add-a-composite-primary-key)