# INSERT IGNORE or Primary Key MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in my ClassSelector DB:

```
students

student_id(P_key) | student_name | hometown

classes

class_id(P_key) | classname | description

student_x_class

student_id | class_id | classname
```

I am trying to enter students into classes, but prevent entering the same student twice in the same class.  I tried INSERT IGNORE, but that blocked me from entering the same student in two different classes.  I have no primary key in the `student_x_class` table.  Could I `student_id` and `class_id` primary keys?

I guess the real question is how do I make a unique value for two columns(`Student_id`, `class_id`)?

Comment: You can make a *composite* PRIMARY (or UNIQUE if you don't it to be the primary) key.  `ALTER TABLE student_x_class ADD PRIMARY KEY(student_id, class_id);`  See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8859353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare them to be either primary keys or unique keys:

```
create table student_x_class (
    student_id int not null,
    class_id int not null,
    primary key (student_id, class_id),
    constraint fk_sxc_student foreign key (student_id) references students(student_id),
    constraint fk_sxc_class foreign key (class_id) references classes(class_id)
);
```

You can also declare the combination to be `unique` instead.