# How to creata a 2-column combination into a primary key in OLEDB with VB.NET

Tags: sql, oledb, dbf, jet, oledbcommand

So I did an update in the "RPD" table and the database does not have a primary key then my solution must create a primary key in the "PNM" column but I can only update only 1 row so the solution is whether it can be by combining the "PNM" column with "NOD" then it becomes the primary key or is there another solution

Thanks

Table name : RPD
These are the details with the product items

| PNM | NOD | ITM | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 01 | Product01 | 10 |
| 1000 | 02 | Product01 | 15 |
| 1000 | 03 | Product01 | 20 |
| 1001 | 01 | Product01 | 15 |
| 1001 | 02 | Product01 | 30 |

Table name : RPG
This is the table master

| PNM | DATE | CUSTNAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 26-11-2022 | A |
| 1001 | 26-11-2022 | B |

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV")
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE RPD ADD CONSTRAINT idxMyTable PRIMARY KEY (PNM)", cn)
                cn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this link : [ALTER TABLE to add a composite primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859353/alter-table-to-add-a-composite-primary-key)

```
  Using cn As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV")
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE RPD ADD CONSTRAINT idxMyTable PRIMARY KEY (PNM,NOD)", cn)

            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
```